# Regain write access to disk in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive

Two weeks ago, I installed `Ubuntu` 20.04 on my Dell laptop in `dual boot` with Windows. Everything was working fine until now. But, today when I tried to write into a file in the hard drive I was unable to do so. I am even not able to create new folder or delete existing ones.
All the operations are working fine for `/home` but for other drives I am not able to perform any write operations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "Other drives", do you mean your Windows partitions?

Comment: @matigo yes i mean Windows partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem with dual boot before.  I think Windows has some kind of drive locking that will make the drive inaccessible if you don't clean exit from Windows.  Try rebooting to Windows, then clean rebooting back to Linux and see if you can access the drive.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.